# Why does Skype on Windows 8 not recognize my user name?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, skype

My brother started to configure the PC with his own Microsoft account and from now every time anyone tries to start a Skype session Skype automatically wants to fuse their accounts (my brother's Microsoft account and people's Skype account) and Skype doesn't allow people to start session until they go on with the accounts synchronization.

Besides that I created my own Skype account but I was lazy on writing all my info down so I synchronized it with my Facebook account so they can took all my info from there but I didn't know that automatically my username would be affected. It says Facebook user name, I wanted to change it but now I know I can't do that.

Then I said well, it's ok, doesn't matter and I tried to initiate session in my old PC but Skype didn't recognize my user name I've tried everything. I want to keep this account because my email, Facebook and Microsoft account are imprisoned there, when I try to change my password Skype send me a code to put in a link but when I do it, Skype web page doesn't recognize it...

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Skype app on Windows 8, then it forces you to sync your accounts, but if you download the Skype for Desktop program for Windows 8, you can get around this.